# Get the most distant images in a set of images with L1 norm

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have a short video sequence containing ~100 RGB images. I stored them in a numpy array, and now I would like to get the 2 most distant images according to the L1 norm.

My first idea was to browse the set, and compare every image to the others, and store every distance in a matrix, then found the max. However, it recquires 2 for loops, and I feel that there may be a more optimal way to do this.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Store the sequence in an array
seq = []
cap =  cv2.VideoCapture('my_video.avi')
while(cap.isOpened()) :
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if (ret == False) :
        break
    seq.append(frame)
# Possibly convert list to np.array here

# Finding the most distant images
distance_matrix = np.zeros( (len(seq), len(seq)) )
for i in range(len(seq)) :
    for j in range(i+1,len(seq)) :
        distance_matrix[i][j] = cv2.norm(seq[i], seq[j], cv2.NORM_L1)

# Get max index (method given on scipy doc)
im1, im2 = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(distance_matrix), distance_matrix.shape)
print("The most distant frames are n°", im1, "and n°", im2)
```

Output would be something like `>>> The most distant frames are n° 0 and n° 17`

It seem that we are always forced to generate every pairs at some point, but it's an heavy method.
Any idea of something more efficient ?

Comment: I believe you can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468643/finding-two-most-far-away-points-in-plot-with-many-points-in-python). It's measuring distance using L2-norm, but I believe L1-norm can also be done by considering only the convex hull. But since high-dimensional data (like image) always causes problems such as [curse of dimensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality), I'm not exactly sure does this apply

Comment: Besides that, a more straight forward way is using `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist`. It is at least better than double for-loop when computing pairwise distances (and *might* be faster using fast generalized matrix multiplication algorithm)

Comment: It's only 100 images. Double for loop it. Don't store the entire distance matrix. Only store the indices if the distance is larger than it has been yet. Hence you store only the largest distance so far, and the indices into seq which created it, as the double loop progresses.

Comment: looks like O(n**2) ...so a double loop.  like the above comment, just do it.  But whatever you're doing will take a while when you start throwing more images in. If that happens CUDA might be your friend. Also, L1 norm won't give you any  idea of *semantic* distance if you ever want that.